# Chamar uma extenção de classe dentro da classe mãe?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Trabalho com uma espécie de framework próprio pra renderização HTML e eventos, dentre outras coisas essenciais, que na verdade é um gerador de código HTML padrão pois posso usar tanto como renderizador direto ou como um complemento pra padronizar o meu HTML.

Dentro desse framework tenho uma classe para incluir as dependências para que ele funcione corretamente, e, posso estender essa classe, para incluir outras dependências que não façam parte do framework.

Atualmente, o modo de funcionamento é um 'joga pra lá e trás pra cá de novo', isso seria, armazeno toda a página em uma variável, e através do DOM acrescento as novas dependências dando um merge entre as `arrays` default do framework e as adicionais da extensão.

```
//Dentro de $page está todo html da página
$page = $VIDB->content($form)->container('fluid')->go('pt-br');

echo \geralComponents\extendsLocal__jsPackages::get_extendeds_packages($page);
```

Método get_extends_packages()

```
public static function get_extendeds_packages($page)
    {
        $extra_packages = self::plus_packages();
        include 'vendor/vidb/assets/php/phpQuery-onefile.php';
        $doc = \phpQuery::newDocument($page);
        $packages = self::get_packages($extra_packages);
        return $doc->find('#js-packages-content')->html($packages);
    }
```

E o método get_packages

```
public static function get_packages($extra)
    {
        $files = '';
        $packages = self::packages();
        if($extra != null){
            $packages = array_merge($packages,$extra);
        }
        foreach ($packages as $import)
        {
            $path = $import['path'];
            $file = $import['file'];
            $version = $import['version'];
            $files .= '<script src="' . $path . '/' . $file . '' . $version . '.js"></script>';
        }
        return $files;
    }
```

Sabendo que pode ser necessário incluir dependências que não estão previstas no framework, eu poderia criar uma extensão para a classe dentro da aplicação que está sendo desenvolvida para incluir essa dependência.
A dúvida que eu possuo em relação a esse processo é a seguinte:

> É possível fazer com que um método da classe mãe verifique se existe
>   uma extensão para a classe, e caso existe, execute algum método dessa
>   extensão de classe?